# Delphi Enums to Variant as varInteger instead of varUInt32

Tags: delphi, enums, variant

Delphi enumeration values are natively defined as unsigned integers - 1, 2 or 4 bytes, depending on the setting of MINENUMSIZE.

I have a case where we are using Variants to transfer data of different data types between applications. All other data types work nicely, but now we realised that the expectation from other applications is that the enumerated values should be signed integers instead of unsigned (and some are really validating this).

Is there a way to configure the automatic variant conversion that the enumeration values would be converted to varInteger, instead of varUInt32?

The background: we are writing library code for OPC UA. OPC UA defines a type called Variant, which has history in Windows Variant, but is now defined in a different way. In practice, OPC UA defines that enumeration values are transferred as Int32 over the wire.

OPC UA also defines a data type called DataValue, which consists of the Value (as Variant), StatusCode (UInt32) and some Timestamp fields.

Now, we are using Delphi Variants for mapping the OPC UA Variant, since it works nicely in general. Now the only major pitfall is that when you write an enumeration value to the Variant it is converted to UInt32, whereas OPC UA expects Int32.

The library takes in Variants (in DataValues) and as an application developer, you can just assign your enumeration values to the DataValue and everything looks good. However, the value has been converted to an UInt32 and when the library code sees this Variant it cannot know anymore that it corresponds actually to an enumeration type of variable.

Should we be able to control the automatic conversion (or actually the native data type of enumerations), we could simply get rid of this problem with that.

If that is not possible, we will really have to invent conversion code, wherever we can, but which can never be 100% certain, after all.

Comment: Can't you simply cast the enum value to integer? `Integer(uvYourThingy)`

Comment: Well, yes, except that this is generic library code and I don't have full control over what values the developers will be writing to the variants.

Comment: That comment doesn't make any real sense to me. You seem to be saying, "how can I exert control over what the variant holds, without being able to exert any control over what the variant holds?" It's like saying, "I want to let developers write arbitrary values to an integer value, but I want to make sure that those values are always positive".

Comment: OK, I should explain a bit more about the background to make it more sensible.

Comment: Which library is it?

Comment: I can kind of work it out. You just need to convert the data type held by the variants to be signed just before you pass them on to the other application. So enforce this at the boundary between your code and the other application that has the requirement to receive signed data.

Comment: I added a more detailed description.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, that's how we can do it, whenever we know that it's an enumeration. But we can't necessarily distinguish it from a normal UInt32 at that moment in all cases.

Comment: So I am looking for ways to prevent this issue in the first place.

Comment: Doesn't seem to me like there is going to be any foolproof way around this. I'm sure you can hook the library code that performs the implicit assignment, but even that would not be fool proof.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, but wanted to get a second opinion. Tx. If you figure out something let me know...

Comment: It's a bit nasty and stupid issue. In practice it shouldn't make any difference whether the values are transferred as Int32 or UInt32, but we hit a case where a certain application was really checking the type at least for one specific value and brought the issue up.

Comment: So, I'd probably enforce this using developer rules. If the point where you pass the value on is too late, enforce this at the point where it is assigned. Don't use variants in your code, use your own type that encapsulates a variant type and has setter methods that can take the right decision because they know at that point they are getting an enum.

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less what we try to do. But there are cases where this might not be enough.

Comment: No there are not. If they only way is through your type, you have total control.

Comment: Well, if you mean that the developers will not overlook the rules that we try to give them....

Comment: As for a code hook, that won't work because you'd end up hooking assignment of Byte to variant as well as enum to variant since they are treated identically by the compiler.

Comment: I meant that there is always a way to write directly to the values, even if we would provide our own encapsulation types.

Comment: "Well, if you mean that the developers will not overlook the rules that we try to give them." OK. But if you change the code to stop them passing variants and force them to use your type, you are in control. If you want to let them write whatever they want directly to the underlying storage, then you made a bad decision and are now paying the price for it. Only you can fix that.

Comment: Yeah that sounds simple, but the type system is quite big and extensible and all that... But tx, we will have to do what we can do.

Comment: Can't you go through, say, TValue or a (generic) type of your own instead of assigning to Variants directly? Don't show any Variant to the "user" of your code. Generics and TValue let you query the type, using TypeInfo and extended RTTI. If it has a TypeKind of tkEnumeration, you can turn it into an Int32 instead of an UInt32.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yeah, that would be the other alternative. I wanted to use Variant, since it provides an almost perfect solution already. It has a drawback of making custom data types a bit more complicated to use, so in that sense it will be good to consider defining our own UaVariant type, which I wanted to avoid. The benefit of Variant is all the automatic conversions between different data types, which come for free.

Comment: And I'd like to add that we are already pretty far with the development - and just learned about this interoperability problem, so I still wish that no major changes would be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't distinguish between assignment of enumerated type to variant, and assignment of integer type to variant. Consider the following code:

```
uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TFoo = (foo, bar);

var
  V: Variant;
  enum: TFoo;
  b: Byte;

begin
  V := enum;
  V := b;
end.
```

The compiler generates the following:

```
Project52946989.dpr.14: V := enum;
00422562 B8389F4200       mov eax,$00429f38
00422567 33D2             xor edx,edx
00422569 8A15489F4200     mov dl,[$00429f48]
0042256F B101             mov cl,$01
00422571 E8BED1FFFF       call @VarFromInt
Project52946989.dpr.15: V := b;
00422576 B8389F4200       mov eax,$00429f38
0042257B 33D2             xor edx,edx
0042257D 8A15499F4200     mov dl,[$00429f49]
00422583 B101             mov cl,$01
00422585 E8AAD1FFFF       call @VarFromInt
```

So even if you hook the library routine that handles such an assignment (`System.Variants._VarFromInt`), you will inevitably pick up assignments of `Byte` values as well as enumerated type values.

The above code assumes single byte enumerated type size, but nothing much changes for 2 or 4 byte enumerated types. Instead of the assignment looking like a byte assignment it looks like a `Word` or `LongWord` assignment, respectively.

Comment: Yeah, that explains it pretty well. Which makes me actually wish for a compiler directive that would enable storing the enumeration values in signed integers instead of unsigned integers. Apparently, it's not possible at the moment so I would just need to make a wish for future Delphi compiler versions...

Comment: I certainly wouldn't want the Delphi developers to add such a thing. You can write `V := Integer(enumValue)`.

Comment: Well, I would :) You can already define whether the values are Byte, Word or LongWord, so I would see this as a natural extension - if we don't consider values that are out of the enum scope. Or what's the danger you see in using signed values under the hood?

Comment: The feature you are proposing doesn't help anybody other than you, and it only helps you because of design decisions that could be changed. I understand that it's painful for you to make that change, but such considerations should not be used to drive compiler design. New features should be added to meet a clear need and provide functionality and utility that does not already exist. Supporting signed enum storage doesn't meet those criteria in my view.

Comment: I understand. IMO, it's kind of a matter of taste, how the enum values are stored internally as it typically doesn't show up anywhere. Ord() is also providing the value as Integer instead of UInt32, so one might even think that it's stored as an Integer. The only case where it really matters, is if you have more than 127 enum identifiers and a Byte data type. It's just internal compiler issue. So, due to interoperability, it would be useful to have control over it. I like Delphi so much, because it really has no limits to what you can accomplish. Now it seems that I have hit the limits...

Comment: The enum size is relevant for binary interop with platform APIs. For instance you typically need to enforce 4 byte enums when calling Windows APIs. If you aren't using the enum for interop then you can let the compiler decide how much space it requires. You have not hit any limits. You have a perfectly clear solution. It's just a little inconvenient to you. What so many people don't understand when asking for changes to compiler/language is that they cost a lot to implement. Emba have limited resources. They have to prioritise. What you suggest has no practical benefit.

Comment: Again, we are talking about binary interoperability, although from a different perspective. Anyways, the situation is clear and we don't need to keep on arguing about it. Should I make a wish to Embarcadero, they may say their opinion of course. I can't rely on that anyways now.

Comment: The difference is that binary interop with the platform is an essential feature